# Consuming WSDL inside ASP.net MVC project

Tags: asp.net, web-services, wsdl

I have an WSDL at my disposal. it's address is : http://gy30.com/webservice/index/wsdl

when i import the WSDL through asp.net "add service references" i can see the "Operations(methods)".
After importing the WSDL i can't see any methods in the object browser. And there isn't any generated classes for this kind of WSDL.

I have read several posts on S/O and many articles about how to consume WSDL by googling, but i didn't find any solution.

http://johnwsaunders3.wordpress.com/2009/05/17/how-to-consume-a-web-service/

what are the problems ?

Comment: I ran this url through wsdl.exe and got errors.  Are you sure this wsdl is valid?

Comment: yes i ran it through wsdl.exe and got errors too, But im pretty sure that this is valid wsdl

Answer (score 3):

If i am not mistaken "Add Service Reference" is for wcf services. What you need is add Web Reference.

This service is legacy and you should use "Add Service Reference" -> "Advanced" > "Add Web Reference" and you will see old beautiful Add Web Reference dialog. And it will add reference but i couldn't consume this service. There was something wrong.

Comment: http://xmethods.net/ve2/Tools.po
and 
http://www.w3.org/2001/03/webdata/xsv
 validate the WSDL

Comment: try consuming service through wcftestclient. it gaves error. Error: Cannot import wsdl:portTypeDetail: An exception was thrown while running a WSDL import extension: System.ServiceModel.Description.XmlSerializerMessageContractImporterError: The datatype 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/:Array' is missing.XPath to Error Source:

Comment: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC>wsdl /l:CS /protocol:SOAP
 http://gy30.com/webservice/index/wsdl,  through visual studio command line and i got errors. I suppose this is sth about NameSpaces.

Comment: I gave it to my friend who is a php programmer and he is using it now.

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/distributedservices/archive/2010/02/04/wcf-client-issue-with-reuse-types-from-referenced-assemblies.aspx maybe this? ...